# Updating jQuery datepicker properties dynamically in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, datepicker

I have datetimepicker component in my project. That is component.html:

```
<div
 class="custom-input-group with-icon"
 [class.inputbox-error]="!valid">
  <input
   #dateInput
   autocomplete="nope"
   [title]="placeholder"
   [(ngModel)]="value"
   [disabled]="disabled"
   [mask]="mask"
   [dropSpecialCharacters]="false"
   [attr.placeholder]="!disabled && placeholder ? placeholder : ''"
   [attr.data-min-view]="viewMode"
   [class]="innerClass"
   [attr.data-view]="viewMode"
   [attr.data-date-format]="dateFormat"/>
     <label *ngIf="!disabled" class="input-icon">
       <svg class="icon-calm" (click)="clickIcon()">
        <use xlink:href="#cal-gray"></use>
       </svg>
       <svg class="icon-active">
        <use xlink:href="#cal-brown"></use>
       </svg>
     </label>
</div>
```

That is my component.ts:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, forwardRef, ViewChild, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges 
 } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { InputComponent } from '../input/input.component';
import * as moment from 'moment';

declare let $;

export declare type DateValidateFn = ((term: moment.Moment) => boolean);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-datetime-input',
  templateUrl: './datetime-input.component.html',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatetimeInputComponent), multi: true 
    },
  ]
})
export class DatetimeInputComponent extends InputComponent
implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
@Input()
public viewMode;

@Input()
public dateFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy";

@Input()
public minDate: any;

@Input()
public maxDate: any;

@Input()
public startDate: any;

@Input()
public mask;

@Input()
public validateFn:  DateValidateFn;

public valid = true;

@ViewChild('dateInput') dateInput: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
$(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({
  startDate: this.startDate ?
    moment(this.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate() : null,
  minDate: this.minDate ?
    (this.minDate instanceof Date ? this.minDate :
      moment(this.minDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()) : null,
  maxDate: this.maxDate ?
    (this.maxDate instanceof Date ? this.maxDate :
      moment(this.maxDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()): null,
  onSelect: (date) => {
    this.value = $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).val().toString();
   }
 });
}

ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
 if (this.dateInput) {
  let date = $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).val().toString();
  if (changes.maxDate && this.maxDate) {        
    $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({ 
      maxDate: this.maxDate ?
      (this.maxDate instanceof Date ? this.maxDate :
        moment(this.maxDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()): null});
  }
  if (changes.minDate && this.minDate) {
    $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({ 
      minDate: this.minDate ?
      (this.minDate instanceof Date ? this.minDate :
        moment(this.minDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()) : null});
  }
  this.value = date;
 }
}

set value(val: string) {
 if (val) {
  const m = moment(val, this.dateFormat.toUpperCase(), true);

  if (!m.isValid()) {
    this.valid = false;
    return;
  }

  if (this.maxDate) 
  {
    if (m.isAfter(moment(this.maxDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true)))
    {
      this.valid = false;
      return;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    if (m.year() > (new Date()).getFullYear()) {
      this.valid = false;
      return;
    }
  }
  
  if (this.minDate &&
    m.isBefore(moment(this.minDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true))) {
    this.valid = false;
    return;
  }

  if (this.validateFn && !this.validateFn(m)) {
    this.valid = false;
    return;
  }

  val = m.format(this.dateFormat.toUpperCase());
}

 this.valid = true;

 super.value = val;
}

get value() {
 return this._value;
}

clickIcon() {
 $(this.dateInput.nativeElement)
  .trigger("focus");
 }
}
```

In my ngOnChanges I need to update maxDate and minDate properties of my existing datepicker. And it updates them. But selected value dissapears from my datepicker. Also i get such mistake: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '09.07.2021'. Current value: ''.

I also tried to update properties with this command:

```
$(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker('options', 'maxDate', 
       this.maxDate ?
      (this.maxDate instanceof Date ? this.maxDate :
        moment(this.maxDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()): null});
```

This also erased my selected value from datepicker but didn't produce any errors.

What I'm doing wrong? This component is used in some other pages and maxDate\minDate values come from them by model changing. And i see they are updating on my element here:
[image]

But they are not updating on popup picker.

**UPD1** Also i tried this variation:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
if (this.dateInput) {
  let date = $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).val();
  if (changes.maxDate && this.maxDate) {        
    $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({ 
      maxDate: this.maxDate ?
      (this.maxDate instanceof Date ? this.maxDate :
        moment(this.maxDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()): null});
  }
  if (changes.minDate && this.minDate) {
    $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker({ 
      minDate: this.minDate ?
      (this.minDate instanceof Date ? this.minDate :
        moment(this.minDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate()) : null});
  }
  $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker('setDate', date);
 }
}
```

It changes my maxDate\minDate in picker popup but also erases selected value in my datepicker. How can I set the value to it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I changed datepicker value setting command to this:

```
let date = $(this.dateInput.nativeElement).val().toString();
......
$(this.dateInput.nativeElement).datepicker().val(date).trigger('change')
```

Now the properties of my datepicker are changing and I'm not losing my selected value.